# dotnet-ef commands not recognized in asp.net core 1.1

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

This is the project.json of my project. I have updated the dependencies to 1.1.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.4.337",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.1",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.4.337",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

The migrations were working fine before. I created Migrations and created the database in SQL Server. Now when I try to create a migration, I am getting this error.

```
dotnet-ef : The term 'dotnet-ef' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet-ef
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dotnet-ef:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried some solutions in the internet, but still getting the error. Am I missing any packages?

Comment: where did you run that `dotnet-ef` script? which environment and what path?

Comment: @S.Serp in the package manager console of VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

Run `dotnet-ef` via Powershell instead of Package Manager console. Or, change the current directory to the project directory (using `cd`) within Package Manager Console.

Also, ensure the Entity Framework Tools package is installed

[see this page](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5392)

Comment: When I change the directory to the project directory inside the solution, dotnet-ef command works. But when I add some commands like dotnet ef migrations add it says **No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.**

EDIT : The same **no project** output is shown in command prompt when executed from the project directory.

Comment: Where can I find powershell in Visual Studio?